# Pandas split column into multiple: performance improvement

Tags: python, performance, pandas

## Aim of the Code:

The aim of the function I'm working on is to take a particular column from a DataFrame that contains multiple `<tag><content>` pairs in the form of a string and expand them into individual columns in an efficient way.

An example file can be found [here](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/H_sapiens/annotation/GRCh38_latest/refseq_identifiers/GRCh38_latest_genomic.gff.gz) (aprox. 3M entries), which can be loaded as a DataFrame with:

```
def load_refseq_coordinates(ifile):
    # https://m.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff3.html
    return pd.read_csv(ifile, sep='\t', comment='#',
                       names=['seqid', 'source', 'type', 'start', 'end', 'score',
                              'strand', 'phase', 'attributes'])
    return df
```

The loaded DataFrame will have a column named `attributes` that has content such as:

| attributes |
| --- |
| ID=NC_000001.11:1..248956422;Dbxref=taxon:9606;Name=1;chromosome=1;gbkey=Src;genome=chromosome;mol_type=genomic DNA |

with different pairs separated by `;` and `<tag><content>` pairs defined with `=`.

The aim would, then to keep the rest of the columns of the DataFrame and get this one converted to:

| attributes.ID | attributes.Dbxref | attributes.Name | attributes.chromosome | attributes.gbkey | attributes.genome | attributes.mol_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NC_000001.11:1..248956422 | taxon:9606 | 1 | 1 | Src | chromosome | genomic DNA |

And the same for all rows of the DataFrame.

## The Issue:

All the solutions I've found so far do **not** scale proficiently and applying them to the 3M entry file takes just too long.

**In the last 3 cases I'll show, performance seems better, as I can test up to 100K in around 4s (with that time is around 10K rows in the first solutions), but it is still poor performance for the 3M rows.**

## Current Solutions:

Note that:

- I'm running this in a Jupyter Notebook, thus the `%timeit` call.
- I'm only checking up to 10k rows to see how it scales (gets too long with more), except the last 3 solutions, as they perform better (thus I time them for 100K rows)

### 1. Series.apply a function that does the double string split

```
def expand_info_string1(df, column='info', entity_sep=';', id_sep='='):
    def do_expand(cell, entity_seq, id_sep):
        data = [x.split(id_sep) for x in str(cell).split(entity_seq)]
        return pd.Series(list(zip(*data))[-1], index=list(zip(*data))[0])
        
    info = df[column].apply(do_expand, entity_seq=entity_sep, id_sep=id_sep)
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns=[column]), info.add_prefix(f'{column}.')], axis=1).fillna('')

%timeit dd = expand_info_string1(df.sample(10), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string1(df.sample(100), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string1(df.sample(1000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string1(df.sample(10000), 'attributes')
```

```
330 ms ± 267 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
299 ms ± 18.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
708 ms ± 375 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
4.4 s ± 263 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### 2. Series.str.split + Series.apply a function to do 1 split

```
def expand_info_string3(df, column='info', entity_sep=';', id_sep='='):
    def do_expand(cell, id_sep):
        data = [str(x).split(id_sep) for x in cell]
        return pd.Series(list(zip(*data))[-1], index=list(zip(*data))[0])
        
    info = df[column].str.split(entity_sep).apply(do_expand, id_sep=id_sep)
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns=[column]), info.add_prefix(f'{column}.')], axis=1).fillna('')

%timeit dd = expand_info_string3(df.sample(10), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string3(df.sample(100), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string3(df.sample(1000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string3(df.sample(10000), 'attributes')
```

```
90 ms ± 28.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
338 ms ± 66.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
553 ms ± 13.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
4.55 s ± 379 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### 3. Series.str.split(expand=True) + Series.apply a function to do 1 split

```
def expand_info_string2(df, column='info', entity_sep=';', id_sep='='):
    def do_expand(cell):
        data = cell.dropna().values
        return pd.Series(list(zip(*data))[-1], index=list(zip(*data))[0])
        
    info = df[column].str.split(entity_sep, expand=True).apply(lambda cell: cell.str.split(id_sep), axis=1).apply(do_expand, axis=1)
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns=[column]), info.add_prefix(f'{column}.')], axis=1).fillna('')

%timeit dd = expand_info_string2(df.sample(10), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string2(df.sample(100), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string2(df.sample(1000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_string2(df.sample(10000), 'attributes')
```

```
236 ms ± 44.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
262 ms ± 19.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.35 s ± 281 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
11.2 s ± 313 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### 4. Series.str.extractall + regex

```
def expand_info_regex(df, column='info', entity_sep=';', id_sep='='):
    
    info_re = re.compile("([^;]+?)=(?:([^;]+))?") 
    info= (df[column].str.extractall(info_re).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                     .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
                     .unstack(level=1))
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns=[column]), info.add_prefix(f'{column}.')], axis=1).fillna('')
%timeit dd = expand_info_regex(df.sample(10), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_regex(df.sample(100), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_regex(df.sample(1000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_regex(df.sample(10000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_regex(df.sample(100000), 'attributes')
```

```
122 ms ± 3.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
129 ms ± 3.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
157 ms ± 3.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
474 ms ± 9.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
4.28 s ± 33.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### 5. Series.str.split(expand).stack + DataFrame.groupby

```
def expand_info_stackgroup(df, column='info', entity_sep=';', id_sep='='):
        
    info = (df[column].str.split(entity_sep, expand=True).stack()
                      .str.split(id_sep, expand=True).reset_index()
                      .drop(columns='level_1').groupby(['level_0', 0]).first()
                      .unstack(fill_value='').reset_index(drop=True))
    info.columns = [x[1] for x in info.columns]
    info.index = df.index
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns=[column]), info.add_prefix(f'{column}.')], axis=1)

%timeit dd = expand_info_stackgroup(df.sample(10), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_stackgroup(df.sample(100), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_stackgroup(df.sample(1000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_stackgroup(df.sample(10000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_stackgroup(df.sample(100000), 'attributes')
```

```
178 ms ± 24.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
269 ms ± 114 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
231 ms ± 87.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
494 ms ± 21.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
4.51 s ± 99.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### 6. Series.str.split(expand).stack + DataFrame.set_index

```
def expand_info_stackindex(df, column='info', entity_sep=';', id_sep='='):

    info = (df[column].str.split(entity_sep, expand=True).stack()
                      .str.split(id_sep, expand=True).reset_index()
                      .drop(columns='level_1').set_index(['level_0', 0])
                  .unstack(fill_value='').reset_index(drop=True))
    info.columns = [x[1] for x in info.columns]
    info.index = df.index
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns=[column]), info.add_prefix(f'{column}.')], axis=1)

%timeit dd = expand_info_stackindex(df.sample(10), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_stackindex(df.sample(100), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_stackindex(df.sample(1000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_stackindex(df.sample(10000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_stackindex(df.sample(100000), 'attributes')
```

```
200 ms ± 91.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
133 ms ± 4.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
158 ms ± 4.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
467 ms ± 16.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
4.16 s ± 252 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Any help in trying to optimise this so that is doable for file with high number of entries would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: Apologies. Fair enough. I'll add the modified function as a new answer, then. Thanks!

Comment: Or, if you want it to be reviewed and possibly further improved, post it as a new question.

Comment: I think I would just rather not repeat the question again, it would just look like a duplication. Posting it as a non-accepted self-answer seems to me more appropriate in this context.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the source data in some other format which is faster to parse? Alternatively, have you considered something like fromfile from numpy?

Comment: Admittedly, the way the file is set up is not optimal. But this is a widely used format for genomic data sharing, so not much can be done on that regard. For the `numpy.fromfile` option, although I am not familiar with the function, for what I read it seems to be for applying during file load time, similar to @sergei-malanin's reply. Ideally I would want to have the two logics (df creation and "expansion") separated

Answer (score 1):

I've prepared a code snippet to solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import datetime as dt

def convert_data(input_file_path):
    print(f"converting file: {input_file_path}")
    output = []
    with open(input_file_path) as f:
        for i in tqdm(f):
            if i.startswith("#"):
                continue
            data = i.split("\t")[-1]
            item = dict()
            for j in data.split(";"):
                k, v = j.split("=")
                item[k] = v.strip()
            output.append(item)
    return output

def process_data(input_file_path):
    data = convert_data(input_file_path)
    print("converting to dataframe")
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


start = dt.datetime.utcnow()
df = process_data("stackOverflow/pandas_split_columns_optimisation/test_data/data")
print(dt.datetime.utcnow() - start)
# converting file: stackOverflow/pandas_split_columns_optimisation/test_data/data
# 3854329it [00:28, 134941.12it/s]
# converting to dataframe
# 0:01:53.006208
```

Please check it, maybe it works for you.

Comment: Hi @sergei-malanin, thanks for your solution. It does not cover several points I was planning to solve (1) it does not keep the other columns, (2) it cannot be guided by column name, (3) it can only be applied on read, (4) it does not append the original column name to the new columns.
That said, the solution is really fast in comparison to mine (0:02:57.497253 for the full 3.8M rows), I suspect because of the DataFrame.from_dict construction. Thus, I implemented that part into its own function following the others I have. Will update my question taking this adaptation into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

@sergei-malanin's answer is really fast in comparison with the options I provided but does not completely meet the needs of the question, namely:

1. it does not keep the other columns,
2. it cannot be guided by column name,
3. it can only be applied on read,
4. it does not append the original column name to the new columns

As such, I took the idea of the `DataFrame.from_dict` construction of his solution and I adapted it to work within my requirements to showcase how it would look like:

```
def expand_info_fromdict(df, column='info', entity_sep=';', id_sep='='):
    def split_to_dict(data, entity_sep, id_sep):
        return dict([j.split(id_sep) for j in data.split(entity_sep)])

    info = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list(df[column].apply(split_to_dict, entity_sep=entity_sep, id_sep=id_sep).values))
    info.index = df.index
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns=[column]), info.add_prefix(f'{column}.').fillna('')], axis=1)

%timeit dd = expand_info_fromdict(df.sample(10), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_fromdict(df.sample(100), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_fromdict(df.sample(1000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_fromdict(df.sample(10000), 'attributes')
%timeit dd = expand_info_fromdict(df.sample(100000), 'attributes')
```

The times I got where somewhat better.

```
129 ms ± 30.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
175 ms ± 124 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
205 ms ± 23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
374 ms ± 6.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.42 s ± 45.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For the 100k sample, this is almost a 40% improvement.

The full 3.8M rows run in just over 3 minutes.